# Trouble using IFERROR with an IF statement that has Multiple Conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a nested IF formula. The return value for some of the IF statements is given by index-matching. If the item doesn't exist on the other sheet, the index-match returns a #N/A, but if there's an error I want the cell to say "Needs Investigation" instead of #N/A, so I've put in IFERROR statements to do this. This works fine. See the first IF statement I have emboldened to see what I'm talking about.

The issue I'm having is with the last IF statement (also in bold). This one is different from all the other because it has multiple conditions (one of which is given by index-matching) and because I specify an Else return value (i.e. If condition is true, then return value, *else* return other value). I want to achieve the same thing as above (that is, if the same #N/A error occurs as above I want the cell to say "Needs Investigation" instead of #N/A). I've put in IFERROR statements everywhere I can think of, and nothing works. Where should I be putting in IFERRORs? Or should I be using something other than IFERROR?

```
=IF(D2="Approved","Approved",IF((AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",E2="Interim Approval")),"Interim Approved",IF(D2="Define","Initial Review",IF(D2="Due Date Approval","Initial Review",IF(D2="Initial Review","Initial Review",IF(D2="No Status","Drawing Not Released",IF(D2="Polaris Review","Polaris Review",IF(D2="Staging","Waiting on Child Components",IF(D2="Supplier Acceptance","Initial Review",**IF(D2="Closed W/O Approval",IFERROR(INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0)),"Needs Investigation")**, IF(D2="Needs Validation",IFERROR(INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0)),"Needs Investigation"),IF(D2="No PPAP Required",IFERROR(INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0)),"Needs Investigation"), IF(D2="Transferred",IFERROR(INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0)),"Needs Investigation"),IF((AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2<TODAY())),"Supplier Late",IF((AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2>TODAY(),C2<$J$1)),"On Track for PV",**IF((AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2>$J$1, INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0))="")),"Due after PV",INDEX(SharePoint!X:X,MATCH('Exceptions List'!A2,SharePoint!N:N,0)))**)))))))))))))))
```

[Here's the same formula, probably easier to look at.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS7xV.png)

If it helps, here's an example of the the first IF statement I emboldened (the one that works) 
[from the spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F0pE.png)

And here's a snapshot of an example of the IF statement I'm 
[having trouble with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9CCJ.png)

Comment: It looks like a bunch of what your formula does could be achieved with a `VLOOKUP` or an `INDEX/MATCH`. Do you have a table of the possible values of `D2`?

Comment: There is also IFNA() available.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `SWITCH` function may help in debugging the issue by making the formula more readable and easier to maintain. The parentheses have been reduced by 15 sets including the outer sets surrounding the **`(`**`AND(...)`**`)`** functions.
Because there is still `IF` nesting in the *"Supplier Submittal"* case requiring a default action (the last nested `IF`'s `FALSE` condition), this default was also duplicated to the `SWITCH` function's default clause.  These defaults `INDEX(MATCH())` are now bracketed by `IFERROR`. The lack of `IFERROR` here likely caused the #N/A error.

The potential for an uncaught #N/A error in the `INDEX(MATCH())=""` test to determine a *"Due after PV"* condition could be fixed locally by returning something other than `""` like this `AND( C2>$J$1,`**`IFERROR(`**`INDEX(MATCH())`**`,"NO MATCH")`**`=""), "Due after PV",`. Having this `IFERROR` return *"Needs Investigation"* would also make the comparison to `""` `FALSE` causing this final `IF`'s `FALSE` condition, `IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()),...` to return *"Needs Investigation"*.
The implemented solution was to bracket this entire final nested `IF` (*"Due after PV"*) in the `IFERROR` and removing the redundant `IFERROR` from this `IF`'s `FALSE` condition.

Occasionally Excel likes to paste multi-line formulas into multiple cells. In this case, paste the formula directly into the formula bar.

*The formula (bar) can be formatted with line breaks by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>*

`=SWITCH(D2,
"Approved", "Approved",
"Define", "Initial Review",
"Due Date Approval", "Initial Review",
"Initial Review", "Initial Review",
"No Status", "Drawing Not Released",
"Polaris Review", "Polaris Review",
"Staging", "Waiting on Child Components",
"Supplier Acceptance", "Initial Review",
"Closed W/O Approval",
   IFERROR( INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)), "Needs Investigation"),
"Needs Validation",
  IFERROR( INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)), "Needs Investigation"),
"No PPAP Required",
  IFERROR( INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)), "Needs Investigation"),
"Transferred",
  IFERROR( INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)), "Needs Investigation"),
"Supplier Submittal",
  IF( E2 = "Interim Approval", "Interim Approved",
    IF( C2 < TODAY(), "Supplier Late",
      IF( AND( C2 > TODAY(), C2 < $J$1 ), "On Track for PV",
        IFERROR( IF( AND( C2> $J$1, INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)) = ""), "Due after PV",
           INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0))), "Needs Investigation")
  ))),
IFERROR( INDEX( SharePoint!X:X, MATCH( 'Exceptions List'!A2, SharePoint!N:N, 0)), "Needs Investigation"))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your formula works fine as is with ONE exception... it has four pairs of asterisks in it that must be removed. Once done, it works great. ( ** are the four character pairs that need to go away.)

In addition, it can be tightened up in a number of ways. You have two places in which different values in D2 lead to the same result. Those can be put together with an `OR()` and the formula will be easier to understand, and probably easier for Excel to calculate. Looks like the last is not an issue because it does not look like a formula that would be copied into 20,000 cells down a column, but a good general principle. The only reason not to, really, would be if any of them could someday need a different result in which case the maintenance to update that would be much tougher. Trade-offs, and we'll assume you know best. But if feasible...

"Tightened up" as I put it, you could end up with this:

```
=IF(D2="Approved","Approved",IF(AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",  E2="Interim Approval"),"Interim Approved",IF(OR(D2="Define",D2="Due Date Approval",D2="Initial Review",D2="Supplier Acceptance"),"Initial Review",IF(D2="No Status","Drawing Not Released",IF(D2="Polaris Review","Polaris Review",IF(D2="Staging","Waiting on Child Components",IF(OR(D2="Closed W/O Approval",D2="Needs Validation",D2="No PPAP Required",D2="Transferred"),IFERROR(INDEX(X:X,MATCH(A2,N:N,0)),"Needs Investigation"),IF(AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2<TODAY()),"Supplier Late",IF(AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2>TODAY(),C2<$J$1),"On Track for PV",IF(AND(D2="Supplier Submittal",C2>$J$1,INDEX(X:X,MATCH(A2,N:N,0))=""),"Due after PV",INDEX(X:X,MATCH(A2,N:N,0))))))))))))
```

or better yet for future work, use `Alt-ENTER` after the TRUE result for each `IF()` so it is easier to read.

Another method to consider for a long line of possibilities that don't much depend upon each other is to use `IFS()`. `Nesting` as done here can run into limits, though not in your formula. But some of them are subtle, not generating a nesting error, but rather seeing a failure either of a function involved, or of the SPILL functionality causing a function to act like SPILL is not a thing yet, though, again, not here. It's just that you don't need the nesting itself, and a long string of `test, result if true` pairs is VERY easy to construct:

1. Pick a set of cells, 2 wide, however many tall, and type the test in the left of each pair and the result in the right. Keep going until you have all the pairs written out in a nice block, 2 by however many (what, 306 of them here?). DO BE SURE to do them in the proper order so the right test/result is done first, second, and so on.
2. Use the third column to textjoin them however works well for you:  using `&`, using `CONCATENATE()`, using `CONCAT()`, using `TEXTJOIN()`... whatever you like so each pair is joined up.
3. Use whatever method you like or have available in your version of Excel to join all of them. I love `TEXTJOIN()` for this kind of thing.

And that's it:  you have your complete string of tests and results for inside the `IFS()`. Copy it, paste special as a value, type "IFS(" before it and ")" after it so you have a finished string, copy, paste as a value, and copy that string. Go to the cell you need the formula in and begin writing it, pasting that string when you come to where it is needed and finish off the formula.

One last thing about `IFS()` is that you can add one last item to the string of tests and results in it:  a final pair using `TRUE` as the test so it will succeed no matter what if Excel gets that far, to be the result if none of the pairs works. You have such a last result, so you would want to use that technique.